# Two spaceships moving away at relativistic velocities in perpendicular directions, how to compute the length contraction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

This has been a question on a test on a modern physics course of the last year and I'm practicing with it because soon I'll have my test.

> Two spaceships of lenght $1km$ move away from earth at speed $0.8c$ and with directions perpendicular to each other. Compute:
>   $a)$ the lenght of those spaceships for an observer on earth
>   $b)$ the lenght of one of the spaceships for an observer on the other spaceship
>   $c)$ the velocity of one spaceship for an observer on the other spaceship.

I had no problem with part $a)$,I used Lorentz transformation and found the lenght of the spaceships for an observer on earth is $0.6km$.

For part $b)$ I'm not sure, I had to do first part $c)$.
Let's say ship $A$ moves in the direction of the $x$ axis and ship $B$ moves in the direction of the $y$ axis corresponding to the frame on earth, then I found the components of the velocity of ship $B$, corresponding to the frame on ship $A$, were $-0.8c$ in the $x'$ direction and $0.48c$ in the $y'$ direction. So my question is:

To compute the lenght of ship $B$ measured by an observer on ship $A$, should I compute the contraction of the lenght of the projection of the ship over the $x'$ axis, due to the projection of the velocity of ship $B$ over the $x'$ axis, then do the same with the $y'$ components of lenght and velocity and finally use the Pytagorean theorem to obtain the total contraction? Or instead compute directly the contraction due to the total velocity of the ship $B$ (with respect to the frame on ship $A$)?
I thought I should obtain the same result with both approaches but I didn't, with the first one the lenght of ship $B$ measured from an observer on ship $A$ is $0.68km$, with the second one the result is $0.36km$. Which one (if any) is correct?

Comment: [This](https://www.phas.ubc.ca/~mcmillan/rqpdfs/1_relativity.pdf) might be of help for this homework set and for others. I think you will find something similar towards the end of pg. 6.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin, thank you. It certainky helps to practice with problems when having the solutions. The problem of page 6 helped me to check my result of the part c) of the test was right, but doesn't help much with part b)

Comment: Well one thing you can do is consider the length in it's component form. In relativity contraction only occurs in the direction of motion. So only one of the components will change. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).